# Bugged function for bits showing

Tags: c, printing, bit

I have implemented this function for showing the bits of a number (I wanted to see all of 9 bits, even though the number could be represented in 2 bits), but after showing 2 numbers, it's bugged and I see a `10` before the bits.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long afisare(unsigned long aux1) {
    int nrBinar[100], i = 1, j;

    while (aux1 != 0) {
        nrBinar[i] = aux1 % 2;
        aux1 = aux1 / 2;
        i++;
    }

    int marime = 9;
    int lipsa = marime - ((i-1) % marime);
    if (lipsa != marime) {
        while (lipsa !=  0) {
            nrBinar[i] = 0;
            lipsa--;
            i++;
        }
    }

    for (j = i - 1; j > 0; j--) {
        printf("  %d", nrBinar[j]);
        if ((j - 1) % 3 == 0) { 
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    //printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    unsigned long n, pi, aux;
    int tst;

    scanf("%ld %ld", &n, &pi);
    aux = n;
    tst = 0;

    printf("%ld", afisare(aux));

    while (tst != 1) {
        aux = aux | pi;
        if (aux == n) {
            tst = 1;
            printf("Coliziune!");
            break;
        }

        printf("%ld", afisare(aux));
        aux = aux & n;
        pi = pi >> 3;
    }
}
```

Input: `3 128`
Output:

```
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 1 1

10 0 1 0
0 0 0
0 1 1
```

Etc. Not a single `10` in my code, or anything like that...

Comment: Show a **complete program** that reproduces the problem, and show the input for which the program fails. See the guidelines for creating a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: My bet goes on the `10` being printed by the code you do not show us ... :-)

Comment: Okay, edited the post right now!

Comment: This `printf("%ld", afisare(aux));` invokes undefined behaviour as `afisare()` does not `return` anything.

Comment: So what should i return if i already have something to show? If i hit return 0, it writes 0 before the text i want to show. I am sorry, i am at the beggining of programming..

Comment: @kannon Its better to provide updates to your question than simply update the main context.  Perhaps edit the question and add an UPDATE: tag with new information. The reason for this is that for people that have commented or answered you change the context and their answer and comments become confusing and even useless.  It's good to progress the question in a way that helps others that run into your original question six months from now make sense of all the contributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `afisare()` return something, by for example adding a final

```
  return 42;
}
```

To the `main()` print statements add a new-line and fix the conversion specifier:

```
  printf("%lu\n", afisare(aux));
```

---

Also fixed the conversion specifiers passed to `scanf()`:

```
  scanf("%lu %lu", &n, &pi);
```

---

To not print any result of `afisare()` do *not* pass it to `printf()`.

```
printf("Before call to 'afisare()'\n");
afisare(aux);
printf("After call to 'afisare()'\n");
```

You then could make `afisare()` a `void`-function (a function returning nothing) as well:

```
void afisare(unsigned long aux1) {
```

and drop the `return` statement.

Comment: While this helped me get rid of the 10, how can i get rid of 42? I mean, i don't want to show any other letter or number.

Comment: @Kannon: So then do not pass `afisare(aux)` to a printf call!

Comment: Then to what? If i have "newVar = afisare(aux);" and then I print this, it will show the return of function anyway. What other way is it to avoid this?

Comment: Don't print it?

Comment: I have to print it. I wouldn't struggle with that if there was no need to print it.

Comment: Why do you have to print it? You already print the bits in the function.

Comment: Oh, i understand now how it works. Thanks a lot, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line: `printf("%ld", afisare(aux));`

You are calling `afisare(aux)`, which prints the 9 bits, and does not have a `return` statement, so the return value is indeterminate. This return value is then printed by the `printf("%ld", ...)`. It happens to have the value `10` on your system at this particular time of day, but it could be anything at all. It is actually *undefined behavior*.

You can correct the problem by **not** printing the return value: just call the function with `afisare(aux);`.

You should also define `afisare` as a `void` function since it does not return anything.

Turning the compiler warnings on would help diagnose such silly mistakes (`gcc -Wall -Wextra`, `clang -Weverything`, `cl /W4`...).

Comment: I love the fact that some people explain better than some teachers on this website ❤️

Comment: @Kannon: I live for this kind of comment :)